# Error: cannot assign requested address, Trying to make a local Server socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, intellij-idea

Using Java 1.7, I'm trying to make a simple server socket that is local. Here is the code snippet:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4342);
```

Doing so gives me the error: cannot assign requested address

[Screenshot of the full code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO7x9.png)

Changing the port to any other number still gives me the same error. I am running the code through an IDE (Intellij).

Comment: Don't post links, and don't post links to screenshots of text. Paste the text *here.*

Comment: Are you quite certain that error is coming from that line of code? The IDE is presenting the error as a compile-time error, which implies some part of the build process is having trouble rather than your code. Your code would print a stacktrace if that line fails, and there's no stacktrace in the error output.